# How can I make a selector on a BottomSheet with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Does anyone know how to position a selector like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuXIu.jpg) (is from telegram in case you need more information) that is always located at the bottom of the screen and inside the bottomSheet using Jetpack compose? The operation should be similar to a StickyHeader of a lazyColumn but at the bottom and displaying at all times.

The operation I have is that of a pager with a row (which would be the selector), but this is always located at the bottom of the bottomSheet even if it is outside the screen.

Comment: "like the one in the image" Where is this "image" exactly? There doesn't appear to be any link to it in your question?

Comment: I just added the image now, it seems that when I added it, it gave me an error and I didn't realize it.